# Renaming top links

Tags: magento

am new in `magento`

I am trying to **rename** the `top links`

But can not found the *corresponding file*

Please help me to locate the file

Thanks in advance

Comment: http://www.matthias-zeis.com/archiv/magento-top-links-anpassen

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
path:design/frontend/base/default/template/page/html/top.links.phtml
```

I don't know for which purpose you need this but

```
<?php
/**
 * @deprecated after 1.4.0.1
 */
?>
```

it is deprecated.
Instead I think magento uses `path:design/frontend/base/default/template/page/template/links.phtml` to display toplinks .
Hope this helps you.

Comment: i want to rename **my account to Account** or **My Cart to cart** etc how i do that

Comment: my account : /app/design/frontend/base/default/layout/customer.xml

Answer (score 1):

Go to System > Configuration  and open Developer Tab. Set "Translate Inline" to Yes.

Once done, you will get a small book icon against the text which you can edit. Do note this doesn't seem to work in Chrome but works fine in Firefox

Answer (score 0):

You can edit Top links name from xml file.
If you want to edit **My Account** to **Account** , just edit in your `themes/layout/customer.xml`.
Look for `reference name="top.links"` and edit the label.